# Ramifications of eating (or forcing to eat) food one doesn’t like

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, lifnei-iver, bal-tashchit-waste

[Avos D’Rebbi Nassan 26:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.26.5?lang=bi) says (translation is from [Artscroll](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422618752.html), and brackets are from their footnotes):

> הוא היה אומר האוכל אוכלין שאינם עולים על גופו עובר משום ג' לאוין שביזה את עצמו וביזה את האוכלין ומברך ברבה שאינה כתיקונה
>
> He used to say: One who eats foods that do not agree with his body [that is, he eats food that is repulsive to him] commits three transgressions: (1) He has demeaned himself [i.e. he has caused himself to become disgusted, and thereby transgressed the prohibition (Leviticus 11:43), *Do not make yourselves abominable*], (2) he has degraded the foods that he ate [and thereby violated the prohibition (Deuteronomy 20:19), *Do not destroy...* This applies to any destructive or wasteful act. Since a different person who is not repulsed by the foods could have benefited from them, this person is considered to have wasted food], and (3) he has recited a blessing improperly.

I’d never heard of this before, and as such, was wondering if this Braisa is ruled in Halacha.

1. Is one really not supposed to make a Beracha on food one doesn’t like? If so, if one eats a particular food for the first time and therefore isn’t sure if he will like it or not, should he make a Beracha, since we’re lenient on a doubt by Berachos (or, perhaps, eat another food he does like that would have the same Beracha)?
2. Are parents in violation of לפני עור for feeding their kids food they don’t like (read: vegetables)?

Particularly for the second question above leaves me wondering whether we don’t pasken like this Braisa. Looking for actual sources in the Poskim.

Comment: Consider YD 116:6

Comment: @DoubleAA אסור לאכול מאכלים ומשקים שנפשו של אדם קצה בהם? Given that the examples all involve vomit, excrement, and the like, I’m not sure that can be extended to include things which only a specific person doesn’t like. Perhaps בל תשקצו only applies to things which are normally agreed are disgusting.

Comment: If you don't like, don't eat it.  But if you must eat it for some reason, you can always say Baruch Dayan Ha-Emet (which is said upon hearing of a good person's death).  My point: You say berachot even for bad things.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi But do you make a Birchas *Hanehenin* - literally, a blessing on benefit - on food one doesn’t like? Also, according to that logic, why don’t you make a Beracha on treif (assuming one isn’t sick or the like that it’s permitted if not obligatory to eat treif)?

Comment: I personally don't like any wine, but can't really abstain because there are so many kiddushes. I do say boreh peri haggafen, but I wonder...

Comment: @DonielF indeed [MT Ma'achalot Assurot 17:29](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968273/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-17.htm) writes *rov bnei adam*: we can't eat foods that most others are disgusted from. I understand the baraita and the SA/MT to apply to truly disgusting foods (see examples there), and not vegetables. So we do pasken like this but it applies to a "lower standard" of food

Comment: @mbloch see Y.D. 84 hilchos tolaim. IIRC there's a machlokes between the knesses hagedolah and the pri chadash and [another big posek]whether bal teshaktzu applies to things which are objectively disgusting (even if it doesn't bother me) or subjective (if it bothers me it's a problem even if most people aren't bothered] or both (either one is a problem). It also get's back to the idea of whether bal teshaktzu is a mitzvah d'oraisa or derabanan (discussed in YD 84 116 and elsewhere, IIRC machlokes drisha and taz).

Comment: This is a good question.

Comment: Nice question. "Thank you Hashem for letting me eat this food which I can't stand, because my parents are making me eat it."

Comment: See Rambam hilchos de'os 3:2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relevant [opinion](https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/3-When-is-a-Bracha-Not-Required.html) by Rabbis Yair Spolter and Shraga Simmons on Aish:
"Only pleasant-tasting foods require a bracha. Food eaten only for health reasons that are not pleasurable to eat, require no bracha."  The whole article is worth reading.

Comment: And the other half of the question? Is it בל תשקצו and בל תשחית?